# <div> will not adapt at the outer <li> height

Tags: html, css, height, html-lists

This is my first question here on Stackoverflow so be kind :3 i'm having a problem with a website in which i cannot manage to make a div get the outer li height. I cannot link directly the website because u would need a private VPN access but i will try to give more information possible. This is the code i'm dealing with:

```
    #boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div {
    margin: 15px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;;
    max-width:90%;
    height: auto;
    /*background-color: #ff6319;*/
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div img {
    max-width: 85%;
}

#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div:hover {
    background-color: #ff6319;
}
```

The circle div has an img inside it and i don't know why but the circle div becomes an OVAL! when i go in hover it gives to the image a strange oval border instead of a perfect circle. any suggestions? sorry for the lack of links but it's in a VPN network.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: Please try to show us your issue in a small and short example with your actual markup

Comment: Try height: 100%;  it will  take up the full height of the parent li element

Answer (score 0):

I can't see more relevant CSS and HTML so there are some options.

Option 1. Show `<li>` as a block element, expand `<div>` height and add more border-radius. Try adding this properties:

```
#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li {
    display: block;
}

#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Option 2. Absolute positioning. This will stretch the `<div>` to the `<li>` border.

```
#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px; //fixed height
}

#boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Non-English speaker, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With your css, what will determine whether #boxdocenti ul.elencodocenti li div is a circle or an oval is the height of your image. If your image is a square, it will produce a circle. If your image is a rectangle, it will produce an oval. Your containing div will take on the height of your image.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest that I could come to the behavior your talking about:
**[Link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxbkz7gr/)**

Your code is somewhat lacking since its only the CSS.
Yet what you describe seems like an `display:` issue.

What I think is happening: your element is by default an `inline` or `inline-block` element but when you hover the display property changes.

So I think adding (or removing) the display property should help.

**Summary**

> Add a `display:inline-block;` on the hover so that it keeps its size and not extends to the full length possible of its parent.